# creating array fields under 'ifdef using perl

Tags: perl

I'm writing a script that creates a database of name, and this database have different versions.
My script is getting the version as input (it has a default version in case of no input)
each database version is based on the previouse versions, but contains some additional names.

I'm trying to find a way to define some of the enteries to my array as a function of the iversion.
Therefore im using something like verilog IFDEF

for example:

```
my @DATABASE = (
  "Arik",
  "Ben",

  if ($version = 1.3) {
    "Suzie",
    "Dan",
  }

  "Roth"
);
```

at this example, the names Arik,Ben and Roth will be at the data base for all versions, but Suzie and Dan will only be at the version 1.3 database

Is there a good way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want, but this may help

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;

my $version = '1.3';

my @database = (
    "Arik",
    "Ben",
    $version eq '1.3' ? (
      "Suzie",
      "Dan",
    ) : (),
    "Roth",
);

dd \@database;
```

**output**

```
["Arik", "Ben", "Suzie", "Dan", "Roth"]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
my @DATABASE = (
   "Arik",
   "Ben",
   $version == 1.3 ? "Suzie" : (),
   $version == 1.3 ? "Dan" : (),
   "Roth",
);
```

or

```
my @DATABASE = (
   "Arik",
   "Ben",
   ( $version == 1.3 ? (
      "Suzie",
      "Dan",
   ) : () ),
   "Roth",
);
```

or

```
sub cond { my $cond = shift; return $cond ? @_ : () }

my @DATABASE = (
   "Arik",
   "Ben",
   cond($version == 1.3,
      "Suzie",
      "Dan",
   ),
   "Roth",
);
```

or

```
my @DATABASE = (
   "Arik",
   "Ben",
   ( "Suzie" ) x $version == 1.3,
   ( "Dan"   ) x $version == 1.3,
   "Roth",
);
```

or

```
my @DATABASE = (
   "Arik",
   "Ben",
);
if ($version == 1.3) {
   push @DATABASE, (
      "Suzie",
      "Dan",
   );
}
push @DATABASE, (
   "Roth",
);
```

or

```
my @DATABASE;
push @DATABASE, "Arik";
push @DATABASE, "Ben";
push @DATABASE, "Suzie" if $version == 1.3;
push @DATABASE, "Dan"   if $version == 1.3;
push @DATABASE, "Roth";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [`Ternary Conditional operator`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator):

```
my @DATABASE = (
   "Arik",
   "Ben",
   $version == 1.3 ? ("Suzie", "Dan") : (),             
   "Roth"
);
```